# How to add report title before header row in SheetJs in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, sheetjs, qjsonobject

I'm trying to export JSON to excel by using SheetJS, but I'm not able to add the title to the table.
Now, I want to add a title in the middle of a row before the header row.

**In export service :**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';

import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';
```

```
@Injectable({

  providedIn: 'root'

})

export class ExportService {

  mimeTypes: any = {

    xlsx: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=UTF-8',

    xls: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=UTF-8',

    txt: 'text/plain;charset=utf-16',

    csv: 'text/csv;charset=utf-16',

    xml: 'application/xml',

    zip: 'application/zip',

    jpg: 'image/jpeg',

    jpeg: 'image/jpeg',

    png: 'image/png',

    mp4: 'video/mp4',

    avi: 'video/avi',

    bmp: 'image/bmp',

    doc: 'application/msword',

    docx: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',

    ppt: 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint',

    pps: 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint',

    pptx: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation',

    pdf: 'application/pdf',

    rar: 'application/vnd.rar',

    webp: 'image/webp',

    '7z': 'application/x-7z-compressed',

    gif: 'image/gif',

    gz: 'application/gzip',

    json: 'application/json'

  };
```

```
public exportExcel(jsonData: any[], fileName: string): void {

    if (jsonData.length > 0) {

      const header = Object.keys(jsonData[0]); // columns name



      const wscols = [];

      for (const head of header) {

        wscols.push({ wch: head.length + 5 });

      }



      const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(jsonData);

      ws['!cols'] = wscols;



      const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = { Sheets: { data: ws }, SheetNames: ['data'] };

      const excelBuffer: any = XLSX.write(wb, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'array' });

      this.saveFile(excelBuffer, fileName + '.xlsx', 'xlsx');

    }

  }
```

I tried the below options and went through some stack overflow answers as well but none of that worked for me :

```
public exportExcel(jsonData: any[], fileName: string,reportName: any, fromDate: any,toDate:any): void {
    if (jsonData.length > 0) {
      const header = Object.keys(jsonData[0]); // columns name               const arr = Object.values(jsonData);   
      const wscols = [];
      for (const head of header) {
        wscols.push({ wch: head.length + 5 });
      }

      const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(jsonData);
      ws['!cols'] = wscols;
      //console.log(ws);

 

      const merge = [
        { s: { r: 0, c: 0 }, e: { r: 0, c: 4 } },
        { s: { r: 1, c: 0 }, e: { r: 1, c: 4 } },
      ];
      ws["!merges"] = merge;
     // XLSX.utils.sheet_add_aoa(ws, header , {origin: -1});
      const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = { Sheets: { data: ws }, SheetNames: ['data'] };
      XLSX.utils.sheet_add_json(ws, arr, { origin: 'A5', skipHeader: true });
      const excelBuffer: any = XLSX.write(wb, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'array' });
      this.saveFile(excelBuffer, fileName + '.xlsx', 'xlsx');
    }
  }
```